# How do I solve this simple but unsolved JPA pagination problem?

Tags: jpa, pagination, spring-data-jpa, pageable

I am trying to make a query using native query and pagination , in my spring boot aplication.

```
 @Query(value = "select * from user pg   ",
     countQuery = "select count(*) from user pg  " ,
    nativeQuery = true)
    Page<User> pesquisar( Pageable page);
```

the Exception threw is like `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column pg.id does not exist Position: XX.`

```
The Class user , of sure , has the id field . but I try to search about this error and I didn't find then I switch for  order by #{#page} and order codes similar but the error continues, changed but persists with another name.
```

Update :

let take a user class sample :

```
Class User { 
@id
 UUID id ; 

@Column 
String nome; 

etc // 
}
```

Comment: Add your `User` class and db stucture also.

Comment: please post the full stack trace and the actually executed SQL statement (from the debug logs)